# Powershell foreach loop with out-file issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to test network connectivity to a list of servers, then dump to a text file ONLY if it returns true. What happens with my code is it includes servers that did not ping. Here's what I have:

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\script\servers.txt
foreach($server in $servers)
{
Test-Connection $server -count 1 -quiet
    if ($True){out-file -InputObject $server, $True -Encoding ASCII -Width 50 -Append c:\scriptoutput.txt}
    else { write-host "server $server could not be contacted"}
}
```

Now what I see in the output file is

```
server1
True
server2
True
server3
True
```

But what I see on the console is this:

```
PS C:\> C:\test.ps1
True
True
False
```

Server 3, which doesn't exist and therefore can't be pinged, still shows up as True in the output file, but reads False in the console. What gives?

Comment: $True is always true.... the else statement is never reached!

Comment: Brilliant! I knew it was something silly. I fixed it with by using:
    if ($entry -eq "True") {out-file -InputObject $server, $True -Encoding ASCII -Width 50 -Append c:\scriptoutput.txt}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is the else statement never reached, but you're always outputting `true` to the file.  Try this instead:

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\script\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $connected = Test-Connection $server -count 1 -quiet
    if ($connected) {
        $server,$connected | Out-File -Enc ASCII -Width 50 -Append c:\scriptoutput.txt
    }
    else { 
        write-host "server $server could not be contacted"
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I like your approach. Last night I realized that I was always outputting true, so I just took it off. Your idea is better!